# Error al registrar por entidad relacionada JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy registrando un usuario con sus datos en esta entidad hay relación con Área y Roles solo debo registrar usuario con un id de área y rol que se envía por post a mi api.

Encontrado temas que debo usar `cascade = CascadeType.ALL o CascadeType.PERSIST`  pero tengo entendido eso se hace cuando insertar las tablas que tienen relacion con usuario pero en este caso solo necesito insertar en usuario una de mis soliciones fue pasar en null el valor de la instancia de Área y Rol ya que desde postman funciona normal ya que Area y Rol son null pero cuando envió desde el cliente queda con `idarea = 0 y idrol = 0`  por esta razón jpa entiende como una doble inserción.

Esta es mi método para guardar.

```
  @Override
    public String createUser(UsuarioVO usvo) {
        String response = "No agregado";
        try {
            if (rolService.searchRol(usvo.getRolid()) != null && areaService.searchArea(usvo.getArid()) != null) {
                if (searchUser(usvo.getUscorreo()) == null) {
                    Usuarios usentity = convertToEntity(usvo);
                    usentity.setUscorreoalternativo(null);
                    usentity.setUsclave(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(usvo.getUsclave().getBytes()));
                    /*usentity.setRol(null); Esta fue una solución
                    usentity.setArea(null);*/
                    usrepository.save(usentity);
                    response = "Agregado";
                } else {
                    response = "Existe correo";
                    logger.warn("Para add el correo: " + usvo.getUscorreo() + " ya existe.");
                }
            } else {
                response = "Area O Rol Inválido";
                logger.warn("El area: " + usvo.getArid() + " o " + "El rol: " + usvo.getRolid() + " no existen");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error al registrar usuario: " + e);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Esta es la clase donde se mapea el json que envian al controller
Aca los valores necesitaria que los setter sean por defecto null

```
@JsonProperty("Rol")
    private RolVO rol;

    public RolVO getRol() {
        return rol;
    }

    public void setRol(RolVO rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Area")
    private AreaVO area;

    public AreaVO getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(AreaVO area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
```

En mi clase usuario tengo estos join:
Hay alguna manera de hacer que en las anotaciones del join el default sea null ?? por que al parecer el insertable y updatable no están haciendo nada nose.

```
// ---- INNER JOINS ----//

    // - TABLA ROL
    @ManyToOne (optional = false)
    @JoinColumn (name = "Rol_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Rol rol;

    public Rol getRol() {
        return rol;
    }

    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    // - TABLA AREA

    @ManyToOne (optional = false)
    @JoinColumn (name = "Ar_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Areas area;

    public Areas getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(Areas area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    // ----  END INNER JOINS ----//
```

El error que me da es al llegar a `usrepository.save(usentity);` en el método de createUser:

```
2021-05-06 22:23:03.278  WARN 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([com.api.Entity.Areas#0])
    Dependent entities: ([[com.api.Entity.Usuarios#<null>]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([com.api.Entity.Usuarios.area])
2021-05-06 22:23:03.278  WARN 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([com.api.Entity.Rol#0])
    Dependent entities: ([[com.api.Entity.Usuarios#<null>]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([com.api.Entity.Usuarios.rol])
2021-05-06 22:23:03.279 ERROR 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.api.Services.Impl.UsuarioService     : Error al registrar usuario: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved befor
```

Comment: En las  relaciones le estás  diciendo  que  no son opcionales:  @ManyToOne(Optional=false)  debería  ser @ManyToOne(Optional=true).

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich ahora el error es: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.api.Entity.Usuarios.area -> com.api.Entity.Areas; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.api.Entity.Usuarios.area -> com.api.Entity.Areas

Comment: pon  el insertable=true, nullable=true en el Join. y agregale  al ManyToOne(cascade.CascadeType.PERSIST)

Comment: La relación  es bidireccional? Rol y Areas tienen un mappedBy Usuaro=

Comment: La solución que me ayudo fue eliminar los setter de Área y Rol en la entity usuario para que que al mapear quedaran en null rol y área

Comment: Hola @Angelita si encontraste la solución por favor agregala como una respuesta a tu pregunta, puede resultar de utilidad para otros usuarios con el mismo problema.